# What is it and how 'huge' is really the formal product of vector spaces?

Tags: tensor-products, tensors

In [here](https://youtu.be/K7f2pCQ3p3U?t=125) the formal product of two vector spaces $V$ and $W$ is defined as the span of symbols $v \ast w$

$$V \ast W = \text{span}\quad\{v \ast w \mid v,w \in \mathbb R \}$$

I guess the wording "span of symbols" implies a completely abstract definition and excludes the possibility of finding a basis, and hence, the statement that the dimension of this space is 'huge'.

Does that imply that each object so constructed would be its implicit basis, such that

$$\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\end{pmatrix} \ast \begin{pmatrix}-1\\2\\\pi\end{pmatrix}$$

would contribute $1$ to the dimensionality, as much as the object

$$\begin{pmatrix}-1\\ -2\end{pmatrix} \ast \begin{pmatrix}-1\\2\\\pi\end{pmatrix}$$

would also increase the dimensionality by $1$?

If so would the cardinality of the set be larger than the reals?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> excludes the possibility of finding a basis

Every vector space has a basis (assuming the axiom of choice) and this one is no exception. But the basis consists of all pairs of vectors from the original vector spaces. As you say, each pair of vectors "contributes one dimension" so for the case in the video of $V= \mathbb{R}^2$ and $W=\mathbb{R}^3$, $V *W$'s dimension is uncountably infinite (the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}^5$).

In particular, it's *not* true that

$$\left(\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 2\end{bmatrix}*\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1\\ 1\end{bmatrix}\right) = 2\left(\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}*\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1\\ 1\end{bmatrix}\right)$$
nor is it true that
$$\left(\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}*\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1\\ 1\end{bmatrix}\right) = \left(\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}*\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1\\ 1\end{bmatrix}\right)+ \left(\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}*\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1\\ 1\end{bmatrix}\right).$$

The "point" of the tensor product is that it quotients out $V * W$ by the symmetries needed to make $V\otimes W$ a vector space spanned by pairs of *basis* vectors of $V$ and $W$ only.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\R}{{\rm I\!R}}$My answer is based on A.I. Kostrikin, Y.I. Manin, Linear Algebra and Geometry, Gordon and Breach Science Publishers, 1997 ([pdf](https://www.math.mcgill.ca/darmon/courses/19-20/algebra2/manin.pdf)), Chapter 4.

Let $V, W$ be two vector spaces. We define a vector space $V*W$, which we will call the formal product of $V$ and $W$, as the linear space that has $V\times W$ as a (Hamel) basis. Note that Kostrikin and Manin denote this by $\mathcal{M}$.

One way to do this is to consider the space of functions $\varphi: V\times W \to \R$ with finite support. Representatives (and a basis) for this set are the functions
$$
\delta_{v, w}(x, y) 
{}={} 
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{ if } (x,y)=(v,w)
\\
0,& \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
Indeed, every function $f:V\times W\to\R$ with finite support (a function of $V*W$) can be written as a finite combination of such $\delta$ functions and each $\delta$ function is identified by a pair $(v,w)\in V\times W$.

Note that $V\times W$ is a vector space when equipped with the natural operations of function addition and scalar multiplication.

We consider the natural embedding, $\delta$, of $V\times W$ into $V*W$, which is naturally defined as
$$
\delta:V\times W \ni (v_0, w_0) \mapsto \delta_{v_0, w_0} \in V * W.
$$
Consider now the following subspace of $V*W$
$$
M_0 {}={} \operatorname{span}
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
\delta(v_1+v_2, w) - \delta(v_1, w) - \delta(v_2, w),
\\
\delta(v, w_1+w_2) - \delta(v, w_1) - \delta(v, w_2),
\\
\delta(\lambda v, w) - \lambda \delta(v, w),
\\
\delta(v, \lambda w) - \lambda \delta(v, w),
\\
v, v_1, v_2 \in V, w, w_1, w_2 \in W, \lambda \in \R
\end{array}
\right\}
$$
We define the tensor product of $V$ with $W$ as
$$V\otimes W = \frac{V * W }{M_0}.$$

The concept of a "symbol" $v*w$ here corresponds precisely to the function $\delta_{v, w}$, which is more concrete as an element of the function space $V*W$ as defined above.

The space $V*W$ is an infinite dimensional space because it has an infinite dimensional basis, $\mathcal{B} = \{\delta_{v, w}; v\in V, w\in W\}$. The space $V\otimes W$ is finite dimesnional whenever $V$ and $W$ are finite dimensional and $\dim(V\otimes W) = \dim V \dim W.$